# Learning Intel Disassembler, What to learn for Intel XED

Tags: disassembly, intel

In order to learn about disassembly and code something like Capstone disassembler, HDE etc. for a function , calculate opcodes etc , Please advise on what I should know. I have some knowledge of Assembly language (NASM) and C, But what do I have to study to learn disassembly and design something like that?